# WAMP vs individually installing PHP, Apache, and MySQL

Tags: xampp, wamp

I am totally new to programming and to some new technologies. Right now I am using WAMP on my Windows Vista. For me, using WAMP is very convenient because I am gonna install once and no need for complicated configuration.

I was OK with it until someone told me that it's not good to use WAMP, EasyPHP, XAMPP, and MAMP because if one of the components such as MySQL crashes it won't work anymore. He said that it's best to install them separately and do a `pain in the ass` configure later.

Please advice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For development and small low volume sites WAMP is just fine!.

If you are not reasonably experienced with installing configuring Apache, php and whatever SQL you are using then a WAMP package is still the better option as a suboptimal configuration is better than a broken one.

Once you are deploying to production and need to deal with larger transaction volumes and security issues then you should really install the components separately and custom configure for your particular needs.

However realistically if you get as far as a small/medium volume production application it will probably be deployed on a rented application infrastructure where all this will be done for you.

So yes stick with WAMP. Time is better spent getting your App right than learning the esoteric settings in the various config files.

Answer (score 3):

WAMP has a clear goal: to provide a usable PHP environment directly out of the box. 0 configuration needed. 0 knowledge needed. You click and it works. If you are a newcomer, this is an *obvious* choice.

Configuring complex software like Apache and PHP is *really* difficult for a newcomer. If you're not actually going to use WAMP in a production environment, there is *no* reason you would have to touch the default configuration.

Making a separate installation for each of those components just doesn't make sense if you're discovering programming. When you're more experienced, you'll certainly enjoy editing obscure configuration files on a distant machine.

My advice is to go for WAMP on your development PC.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that the 'crash argument' is valid. It makes no difference if you install a bundle or single component - the problem is find the cause and to fix it. The bundles are designed for an easy start, the price to pay is that the configuration isn't meant for production use. I would prefer to learn using a local bundle and apply my knowledge/skills when I configure a production server (without any pain, because then I can).

Answer (score 2):

WAMP--Windows Apache MySQL PHP
XAMPP--X(Multi OS) Apache MySQL PHP Perl

Wamp is better for newbies, To install, customize easily and learn the basic things in user friendly. Mainly on enabling the dll's in wamp is more easy than Xampp. But it will create many problems as kind of, when we restart the server it may not restarted properly and you need to do additional thing as restart your system or need to re-install wamp. The main drawback is, it support Windows Alone. Normally nowadays everyone prefer to go with Linux server as it have more security purpose. Hence if u develop using wamp, its useless for Linux Production Environment.

So i would suggest Xampp and its also a developer's choice.

It have more features than Wamp, 
they are:

1. Tomcat
2. Perl
3. Supports Multi-OS
4. Filezilla FTP
5. PHP4
6. PHP5

It is better to restart the server separately for MySQL, Apache, Mercury, FTP.

For enabling the dll's in Xampp is not a hard task for developer and its a stable server.